# A conjecture in number theory with twin primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures

It's a conjecture found with the help of Wolfram Alpha :

> Let $p_i$  be the first primes and $n> 5$ with $n$ an odd natural number numbers we are interested by the quantity :
>   $$A=(1+p_1\times p_2(1+p_3\times p_4(1+p_5\times p_6(\cdots(1+p_n\times p_{n+1})^{\frac{1}{2}})\cdots)$$
>   Or
>   $$A=(1+2\times 3(1+5\times 7(1+11\times 13(\cdots(1+p_n\times p_{n+1})^{\frac{1}{2}})\cdots)$$
>   Where $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ are twin primes numbers

### Example

$$(1+2\times3(1+5\times7(1+11\times13(1+17\times19(1+23\times29(1+31\times37(1+41\times43)^{\frac{1}{2}}))))))=311677481085187=7×43×433×2391393439$$

### Conjecture 1

> The last digit of $A$ is seven .

### Conjecture 2

> If $A$ is not a prime number then $A$ is divisible by $7$.

I try to work with divisibility rule for small numbers but it becomes insane with big numbers .

I'm a very beginners in number theory so if you could use elementary tools it will be cool .

Thanks a lot for your time and patience .

Comment: How far have you tested this?  Your formula appears to assume that $n$ is odd...are you assuming that as a requirement?  If not, what does your formula mean  when $n$ is even?  For instance, $p_{18}=71$ is the least of a twin prime pair.  What is $A$ in this case?

Comment: Typo:  meant to write $p_{20}=71$.  Same question, though.

Comment: Ok let me try it .

Comment: Well, my point was the parity.  Since you multiply your primes in pairs, it looks like you need $n$ to be odd.  I don't understand what your formula means if $n$ is even.

Comment: Oh I see let me fix it .

Comment: Actually, $p_{10}=29$ is a smaller example.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Have you a idea of proof lulu ?

Comment: I asked you before, how far have you checked this?

Comment: I have tested until wolfram alpha doesn't recognize my question .

Comment: And how far is that?  Note:  to get at the last digit, you can work $\pmod {10}$.  WA shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Oh $i=48$ but how to work with $(\operatorname{mod} 10)$ with wolfram alpha?

Comment: So...you've only checked the examples $p_{7},p_{13}$?  That's not much evidence.  In WA  the function Modulo[m,n] returns $m\pmod n$.

Comment: I try until $p_{48}$ thanks for the advice with WA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Conjecture 1**

We know that $p_3 \times p_4 \times (\text{stuff})$ is a multiple of $5$, so it ends in a $0$ or a $5$. We then get that $1 + p_3 \times p_4 \times (\text{stuff})$ ends in a $1$ or a $6$, and so 
$$
p_1 \times p_2 (1 + p_3 \times p_4 \times (\text{stuff})) = 6 \times (\text{something ending in } 1 \text{ or } 6)
$$
which means that it ends in a $6$, or a $6$. Add $1$ to that and you get something that ends in a $7$.

**Conjecture 2**

Here we have that $p_3 \times p_4 \times (\text{stuff})$ is a multiple of $7$, so $1 + p_3 \times p_4 \times (\text{stuff})$ is $1$ more than a multiple of $7$. It follows that
$$
p_1 \times p_2 (1 + p_3 \times p_4 \times (\text{stuff})) = 6 \times (\text{something } \equiv 1 \pmod 7)
$$
is $6$ more than a multiple of $7$. Add $1$ to that and you get a multiple of $7$.

Comment: It's very clear for me thanks a lot !